# Conditional operator in C

Tags: c, ternary-operator

can every if...then...else statement be converted into an equivalent statement using only ?:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While any use I can think of for the ternary operator can be implemented as an if/else, the converse is not true; at least not without resorting to perverse and pointless 'tricks' that yield no benefit in terms of performance, readability, or maintainability.

The syntax of if/else is:

```
if( <boolean expression> )
    <statment>|<statment block>
else
    <statment>|<statment block>
```

whereas the syntax of the ?: ternary operator is:

```
<boolean expression> ? <expression> : <expression> ;
```

The important thing here being that an `<expression>` and a `<statement>` are different syntactic elements.

The very limited usage of the form:

```
if( b ) x = y else x = z ;
```

can be implemented as:

```
x = b ? y : x ;
```

but here the restriction is that the same variable is being assigned in both the true and false clauses, (and therefore y and z are both at least convertible to the type of x).  So it may be said that any *conditional assignment* can be implemented with the ternary operator (after all that is its primary purpose).

Now since a function call is a valid expression, you could wrap the true and false clauses in separate functions, but to do that simply to prove a point is somewhat perverse:

```
if( b )
    true_stuff() ;
else
    false_stuff() ;
```

is equivalent to:

```
b ? true_stuff() : false_stuff() ;
```

and those functions can contain any code at all.

So to convert the more general if/else case to a ?: operation, the true/false statement blocks must first be wrapped in separate functions.  However even then Neil Butterworth's examples will defeat this approach since the behaviour of `break`, `continue`, and `return` affect control flow beyond the confines of the if/else construct, (although perhaps those are also examples of code you want to avoid!). The presence of a `goto` in the if/else would also defeat this approach. .

I think in the end, even if you could, why would you want to?

Answer (score 7):

The code:

```
if ( flag ) {
   exit(1);
}
else {
   return 0;
}
```

cannot be converted into:

```
flag ? exit(1) : return 0;
```

**A better example** - this would be inside a loop:

```
if ( flag ) {
   continue;
}
else {
   break;
}
```

cannot be converted to:

```
flag ? continue : break;
```

Comment: You could do `return (flag ? exit(1),1 : 0)`, but that's just ugly.

Comment: @Pavel Radzivilovsky Take a look here: http://codepad.org/YU33Orwj

It won't work only if we assign void to some variable, except it work perfectly.

Comment: I thought I came up with a method that made the answer yes; then looked at your examples!  In the end my advice would be to use the constructs *appropriately* not perversely - which renders the question irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Both "branches" of the conditional expression must evaluate to the same type, and that type must not be `void`.

For example, you could do this:

```
x > 0 ? printf("Positive!\n") : 0;
```

because `printf` return `int`. (I would only use this in a round of code golf, though; in fact, [I just did](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568090/code-golf-word-search-solver/2568590#2568590).)

But you cannot do this:

```
x > 0 ? exit() : 0;
```

because `exit` returns `void` (or, actually, doesn't return at all).

Comment: Can't you write a function that returns `int` and that calls `exit(0)` and then returns 0 for example? Then do `x > 0 ? myExit() : 0;`. This will work, so I think the answer is actually "yes, if you have nothing better to do".

Comment: You could, but it would be pointless. Also, this doesn't work if the if/else statement contains substantial code, instead of just a single statement or two.

Comment: Your first point about type and void is only true if you attempt to assign the result of the ?: or use it as an argument.  Your second example as it stands compiles and runs in MSVC++2008 at least.

Comment: @Clifford: Hmm, you're right. Interesting. Is the `0` cast to `void` in that case?

Comment: It appears to be regarded as simply a null statement.  For example `int main(){ 0;}` compiles but generates no code for the 0; statement (or in fact any other unassigned constant expression).